# Can't publish comments or answers

Tags: support, answers

I'm trying to publish a comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705692/what-are-the-framework-options-for-a-mobile-app).

When I click **Add comment** I get:

> Only 1 comment allowed per 5 seconds; timer reset.

I wait 5 seconds but I keep getting the same message.

Trying answering I get a different notice:

> Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
>
> ```
> Sorry, posts can't contain that content.
> ```

I report my reply, maybe it's something wrong with it:

> There are [a lot of
>   them](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=javascript+framework+mobile). First result
>   from my browser:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086863/best-cross-mobile-javascript-framework-iphone-android.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[You can't post `Let Me Google That For You`-Links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links).

Even if you could, doing so would result in Moderator actions, or worse, Spam/Abuse-Flags which would cost you reputation.

It's neither nice nor helpful to post links against the results of a searchmachine, because they're not static.

Answer (score 11):

You'll find the answer here, at the very top of the page:

http://tinyurl.com/5rq7yzl

Comment: You violated the rule of LMGTFY-Links **and** URL-shorting services...but heck that's an awesome answer!

Comment: @Bobby: Yes, I felt like it was justified here.

Comment: @Guandalino: Sure, no problem. And the first error message is pretty standard. Comments are rate-limited for everyone. You can only post 1 every 5 seconds. The same rule applies for edits to comments. But that one seemed self-explanatory.

Comment: The real problem here is that the error message is completely useless.