# Put an end to the tyranny of "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource" questions

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Please disallow *any* [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7445292/warning-mysql-fetch-array-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql) whose title is

> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Or whose body content contains this text for users of less than 500 rep.

There are a million, bazillion, gazillion duplicates of the same old "I didn't check the result of `mysql_query`" "question" and at times they're pouring through at a rate of one every couple of hours. It is no longer tractible to go through them all and mark as dups manually, so perhaps we can have some sort of script to do this for us, whilst we're at it?

Comment: Loosely related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105365/stack-overflow-has-too-many-too-localised-new-questions

Comment: +1 for the spirit of the suggestion - although getting them *blocked* is probably unrealistic. Still, having a canonical version would be nice - I tried something to that end once in  [Reference: What is a perfect code sample using the mysql extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6198104)

Comment: I posted a [generalized and less frustrated version of this proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106415/require-a-privilege-to-ask-a-question-whose-title-already-exists).

Comment: @phihag: Touché ;)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal The prompt closure as a dup is karmic ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Blocking them *automagically* can not be a solution.

But you could follow the approach you know from the [c++-faq](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq). Yes, it is not practical if you have loads of questions and going through them, but banning a words/phrases can not be the solution to this. What if someone has a legit question about that error? Or wants to include it in the context of a bigger question?

Also new users have shown a very good resistance against helpful messages and sometimes very creative ways to get around them.

Comment: If you read this question again, you'll see that the problem here is one of sheer volume. I know how to close as duplicates, but this specific topic is like a torrent of urine that just won't stop torrenting. It's become intractible to stop it.

Comment: (And, FWIW, I have several questions and answers on the `c++-faq` tag myself.)

Comment: Well then, I'll stick to my opinion that banning them automatically will not fix it.

Comment: How so? By definition, if the source of the problem is terminated, the problem will go away.

Comment: Because people have always been creative if it comes to outrun automatic bans. Also, to be honest, I'd like to keep them away from Meta (`Why can't I post my question!!!1!1!!`). There's also the slight possibility that somebody will have valid question containing that text/error message.

Comment: If someone's determined enough to decide to ignore "your question has already been answered; cannot post question" and re-word their question to get around it, they were probably determined enough to do a search or just read the frickin' manual in the first place. Ideally.

Comment: I wish it would be that way. :( When the LMGTFY-Ban kicked in, people started to use URL-Shorteners to hide that stuff. Hell, [some of them even came to Meta asking why they can't post it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98644/cant-publish-comments-or-answers). And there are a lot of options, like a PasteBin, `I receive error, please look here: pastebin`. There are also still people coming here asking why they can't post questions, quoting the exact error message *with the link to the FAQ in it*.

Comment: Still, _something_ has to be done.

Comment: On that one I totally agree with you...but I don't believe that an automatic ban is that solution. And before you ask, no, I don't have a better idea right now, sorry.

Comment: I wasn't going to say it :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it's necessary to disallow posts with particular titles like this. However, I *would* support—and have already requested—a feature to [add title uniqueness to the heuristics for detecting low-quality questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104914/162705). Your concern here seems to be a specialized case of my request.

I think that you are grossly overstating the number of questions with "supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource" in the title, however. I made a simple [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112772/duplicate-mysql-questions) to search for posts like this (flag away!) and it only found 55, *not* "a million, bazillion, gazillion duplicates" that are "pouring through at a rate of one every couple of hours."

Comment: [Another 30-odd here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112770/duplicate-mysql-questions)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Thanks; added. (By the way, ***did we just get name auto-completion in comments?***)

Comment: @Ch: I don't know; did we? [edit: no]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53404/tab-name-completion-for-comments-please

Comment: @Tomalak protip: conversations between the OP and 1 other person don't need `@postowner` mentions and the completer knows this

Comment: @JeffAtwood: Ah, ok. Seemed to work for Chris, though?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Yep, name autocompletion still works for me. Perhaps the post owner can use it even when the other person cannot?