# Is it off limits to even mention Google now?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I just had a conversation with a mod about a comment telling the OP to use Google.

When I see an *exceedingly* trivial question (and I mean exceedingly), I will

- Google the question's title (or whatever the appropriate keywords are)
- Check whether a crystal-clear answer to the question is among the first three to five hits (max) on a good site (preferably SO)
- If it is, leave a comment on the question pointing out that this can be Googled using this and that search term; in varying degrees of friendliness, but never worse than, say, `Google "how to add a number to a variable in JS"`.

The comment I mention was removed by the mod.

Now, I can see how  "Google xyz" can be a bit on the curt end; I will see to it that I regularly pad that with a bit of nicety. **However**, I stand 100% behind the practice of telling people to learn to Google. How can you program machines when you can't use a search engine?

Is even *mentioning* Google now off limits, and comments to that end subject to deletion?

Comment: We must refuse to acknowledge that the rest of the intertubes exists

Comment: Did you google for "Google ban on Stack Overflow"?

Comment: @Oded that's so rude, man. :P

Comment: Disagreement is putting it harshly, no?  I think it was a civilized conversation.

Comment: @casper really? I can't find a more harmless word. :) (Edit: ah, that's better!)

Comment: What is this Google you speak of?

Comment: BTW, what makes you think it's a moderator removing those links? If enough regular users flag your comments, they get removed too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, he spoke with the mod who deleted it...

Comment: @Pekka I just did. It returned this question.

Comment: If this wasn't Pekka, we'd all have pointed this out.. Unless the mod *stated* he removed the comment, you just don't know..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, I removed the comment.  Chances are though Pekka might not have even known if I hadn't told him that he should have known better.  There's no debate about who removed the comment, and the conversation isn't about why I removed *that* particular comment, but rather what should be done on the site for these comments in general (in that it hasn't really been discussed before).

Comment: @casperOne: Thanks for confirming :-)

Answer (score 26):

Questions of possible rudeness aside, Stack Overflow has a *lot* of Google Juice.

That means, in a very short period of time, someone searching for your suggested term will find that self-same question and answer highly placed in search results.

> recursion (*n.*): see - [recursion](https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion&oq=recursion)

It would probably be best to downvote and possibly close for lack of search effort.

Answer (score 25):

Here's my take on it (being the mod that had the conversation with Pekka).

We have a [very clear policy on LMGTFY links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links).  What you're doing doing is LMGTFY without the LM, the FY, and the link.

So where's the value that you're adding here?  If anything, you're taking the pageview away from Stack Overflow.  Additionally, if you've taken such care to Google the result and make sure it was directly pertinent to the question at hand, why not turn that into an answer?

It should also be noted that Google won't always return the same results for two separate users.  Robert Harvey and I actually came across this issue while chatting, I posted the results for a Google search, he posted his, and the order of the items was reversed (we were each referring to the "first" result, only to find they were different for each of us for the same exact search term).

Of course, over time, links will rise and fall changing what is shown in the top few results, and those links might not necessarily answer the question at hand correctly anymore, rendering your search suggestion moot.

If we want Stack Overflow to be the *canonical* resource for Q & A, then if you're going to make a search suggestion in the comments, then *that* comment should be canonical as well.  The fact that it's not a direct link prevents it from being canonical over time (granted, not everything is immune to the effects of time, but there are things we can do to make it *more* immune).

If you're just going to leave a comment, then the best thing is to add a direct link to the resource that you feel answers the question.  If you don't, it's very possible in the future that what you see now is not what will be shown to the user later.  The web is in no way a static place, and while links do die, the volatility of a search term suggestion seems much higher than a direct link to a resource.

Specifically to your second point, if the link is to *another* question on Stack Overflow that answers the question, then you should be casting a vote to close as duplicate (assuming it is a duplicate).

If it's an *exceedingly trivial* question that borders on it being closed (or is an outright candidate for closure) then why not flag it or cast a close vote?

The point is, if you're going to take the energy to perform the search and find out what the best answer is, there are much better options that will benefit the site overall at your disposal than leaving a comment which just says "Google this".

Comment: Even if that were true, that wouldn't be an argument for deleting said comments.  The argument that, "You could have done something else that is more beneficial," applies to literally everything that anyone ever does.  We are not perfect.

Comment: @Servy No, but to be blunt, leaving that comment is lazy.  If one is going to make sure that the link is a quality link, they might as well finish the deal.

Comment: For the record, I'm very open to how to make these comments more productive. As said, I put a lot of effort in them

Comment: @Pekka I mentioned in one of the initial comments (as I have here) why not an answer?  Comments don't really help the site overall.  And frankly, even if they were accepted, chances are [some schmuck of a mod](http://stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone) is going to go and blow away the comments anyways.  Why focus on making the comment (which most everyone agrees are worthless) better when you can make a *post* better?

Comment: @casperOne My point is that this entire answer is an argument to discourage people from doing this, but it doesn't seem to me that it's grounds for deleting the comment.  The fact that it was lazy, or could be better, just isn't *enough* for me to justify that action.

Comment: @Servy It wasn't deleted because it was lazy, if you look at the comment trail that's left, the rationale is because of the first point, that it's a variation of LMGTFY, which is explicitly banned on SO.  I urged Pekka to post this on meta to get a clear community consensus on the issue.

Comment: Though not deleting it might leave those who are truly lazy (and did not put in the work that Pekka did) with the idea they can leave similar or perhaps even more crude comments without the underlying effort.

Comment: If someone leaves a comment with "Try googing for 'XYZ'" and I don't believe it will return good results I'll google it.  If it doesn't return helpful results then would leave a comment saying, "Googling 'XYZ' doesn't seem to return helpful results".  I may then proceed to provide a more valuable hint or answer if I knew enough about the question.  While I can agree with the ban on LMGTFY due to it's rudeness, telling someone to "try googling for 'XYZ'", if it does return results, is in my mind just fine.  If it doesn't help the OP, they can say so and go from there.

Comment: @Servy And therein lies the problem.  If people come here and they see that the answer is in the comment, which leads them to Google and then *somewhere else*, then we've already failed in our mission here.  Stack Overflow is not a link repository or Google dump, we're here to provide the answers *here*.

Comment: Last I checked providing a link to useful/helpful content as a comment (rather than as an answer) was still allowed.  Your last comment would lead me to believe that is no longer the case.

Comment: @Servy That's not what is being done.  First, no link is being left, second, it's a directive to go somewhere that will give you a list of links which you then have to decide which is best for you.  I'm not sure how that is useful or helpful.  Also, you seem to have a passionate opposing view.  Why are you not posting that as an answer to this?

Comment: I realize that's not what's being done here, however, your comment would lead me to believe that it's not appropriate to post links as comments.  If that's true, it's a radical statement not to just be overlooked.  As for it being useful, I can recall a number of instances (one earlier today) in which someone asking a question simply didn't know the terminology or buzzwords that would help Google find good results, and when I told them what I searched on google they thanked me and went on with their day.  Providing those words was all the help that they needed.

Comment: *"What you're doing doing is LMGTFY without the LM, the FY, and the link"* and the rudeness of providing a link that fools the one who clicks it into thinking it might be a canned answer. Spelling it out like "Google for ..." is much, MUCH, friendlier in my opinion. To me, banning LMGFT is good, but I disagree that mentioning Google is the same.

Comment: @Servy You're taking the answer *way* out of context at this point.  If you can show where I said that posting links as comments is inappropriate, then I'll revise that, but at this point, I don't see it, and you're putting words in my mouth.

Comment: @Arjan LMGTFY wasn't banned completely because it's rude, but also (if not more so) because it doesn't actually do anything but redirect you to a search result.  That's not an answer, and it's not seen as generally helpful because it doesn't indicate *which* link is helpful.

Comment: @casperOne *" If people come here and they see that the answer is in the comment, which leads them to Google and then somewhere else, then we've already failed in our mission here. Stack Overflow is not a link repository"* So this is the statement in question.  To me, it seems like this applies equally to Google as it does to anything else that might be linked.  I'm not saying that you said we can't post links, I'm *asking* you if you said that we can't post links, because that's what it seems like to me.  If we *can* post links in comments, then how are any other links different from Google?

Comment: @Servy You're misinterpreting.  Again, *no link was actually posted*.  As for links in comments, they're fine, but there was *no link in question here*.  Also, while links in comments are ok, they are inherently less useful than actual *answers*.  Links directly to content that addresses the issue are better than links that point to lists of other links where it's unclear what the actual answer is.

Comment: Yes, I know no link was posted.  I am taking a statement you made and extrapolating it to other situations, because it appears to have nothing specific to this situation about it.  Why does that statement not apply to the general case?  Since links are less useful than answers, why are links not deleted?  Your justification for deleting the OP's comment was that it could have been more useful, and links are less useful than answers.  My point here is that it's not a valid justification.

Comment: @casper `If one is going to make sure that the link is a quality link, they might as well finish the deal.` I get what you mean, and it would be zero problem to do that effort-wise, but I often can't bring myself to doing that anymore. It feels too much like kindergarten, especially when you do it the hundredth time and you can get the perfect answer by literally entering the question title into Google. Posting answers to those "questions" feels broken and makes you doubt the point of this great enterprise that is SE. But maybe I should just quietly downvote and closevote and walk away...

Comment: @Pekka, for what it's worth: I still feel you're helping people a lot better with such link than with not commenting/answering at all.

Comment: @Arjan thanks. Yeah, I think there is value in doing this. On the other hand, I can see the problem with "Go google" type comments... I think we keep coming back to the ["General Reference" idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason)

Comment: @Pekka `It feels too much like kindergarten` Heh, wait until you get a diamond, mate...

Comment: @YannisRizos romper room

Comment: @Pekka Thinking more about this last night, it reminded me of a case where Robert Harvey and I got two separate results searching Google at the same time for the same thing.  That said, it speaks also to the fact that pages can rise and fall through the ranks, and why a direct link is less volatile than a suggestion to search on Google.  I don't think we really looked at the value of such a suggestion over time yet in this conversation, and I think it's a very important piece. We want SO to be the canonical resource.  If you're going to suggest a search, then it should be canonical as well.

Comment: @casperOne I'm not sure this holds true for "how to concatenate a string in JavaScript" type questions, though - not SO should be the canonical reference for that, but the *manual.* There's a limit to being a canonical reference, and to me, this is where the line should be drawn

Comment: One might be able to make the argument that leaving a constructive comment that says "Hey Bob, try Googling XYZ" might help the person improve their *next* question by teaching them how to be a better user. I'm not sure deleting these comments is the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

There has been a lot of talk about broken windows lately, and I personally begin to believe that the theory is not without merit.

And we are all social animals, whether we [qualify as jackasses](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/) or not. This means, among other things, that we adapt to what we perceive as the accepted and/or expected behaviour of a new group we are about to enter.

If the group makes it clear that it is perfectly acceptable to ask for everybody's help (and time, and effort) to solve a problem that a decent programmer could be expected to at least solve half way by doing a bit of research by themselves, then that is exactly the behaviour you get from new (and even some old) users.

This being the Internet, the very first step of any research is to type in a search term or two in your favourite  search engine.

Now, I contend that in order to avoid too many broken windows in the wall that protects the community's time and effort (and sanity), there needs to be a mechanism which guides users (old and new) to do some initial research before asking other people for a slice of their time and limited mental energy. I also contend, as mentioned above, that on the internet research is primarily done through search engines.

This is where I need some help to understand:

What is the best way to direct a user to do some initial research of their own, without mentioning the concept of a search engine, or specific brands of internet search engines?

Subquestion: Is it allowed to mention that doing this form of research is generally considered an easy task?