# List of banned URLs

Tags: discussion, support, chat, lmgtfy

A while back, I posted a link to Let Me Google That For You in chat.  It was picked up by the SO bot and I got banned for 30min.  Not fun.

For future reference, is there a complete list of banned URLs available?  Can this be added to the [Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq)?

Comment: I never knew anything was "banned" on chat. People must have just flagged you.

Comment: What @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA said, the 30min suspension is most likely a result of people flagging your messages and _not_ of a filter. If LMGTFY was banned in chat you wouldn't be able to post it in the first place.

Comment: @YannisRizos exactly...

Comment: +1, fair enough to have list of sites that are "frowned upon".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes, but nothing in chat (that I know of yet) is "banned"

Comment: There is no such thing as a "List of banned URLs." Enough People (actual humans) flagged your message as offensive, and thus you got auto-suspended. Out of curiosity, why do you bring this up now? It was almost three weeks ago.

Comment: @balpha We've got a chat bot in the JS room.  If lmgtfy and other links were autobanned (like I thought they were), [it could be a serious security issue](https://github.com/Zirak/SO-ChatBot/issues/13).  This wasn't me complaining about the ban.  I'm sorry if it came across as that.

Comment: @SomeKittens but they are not.... and it did come across as a complaint. Think before posting about being banned or anything of that nature. It usually reflects back at you on meta... I know from experience....

Comment: @balpha fair enough, what about list of sites that are frowned upon by many users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I **do not** believe LMGTFY is banned in chat (or any other URL for that matter)

What probably happened was that someone flagged your post, and others flagged it as well to make it so that you were banned for 30 minutes.

If it was really "banned", then there would [be a message stating so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/34456/155556) on chat.

Comment: Your link has nothing to do with chat.  I was banned by a bot, not a mod.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like someone flagged it; not sure if chat has a blacklist actually. And if it did, it just prevents you from posting X, it doesn't let you post it, then suspend you for it.

Comment: @SomeKittens you have proof of this mysterious "bot"? I do not know of any SO bots in chat that exist (yet)

Comment: It was either Community or Feeds.  I don't remember which.

Comment: @SomeKittens niether of them are active on chat. Feeds just posts from a feed. and Community doesn't do anything (that I know of) in chat.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Community sometimes posts her sonnets in chat. Typically they are horrible.

Comment: @YannisRizos o rly? Do you have an example? I never knew that Community was a poet! ^_^

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Hm, I usually delete them on sight, so nope.

Comment: @YannisRizos if you don't have proof. It doesn't exist! :-P