# Use of OP or Stack Exchange-ese acronyms

Tags: discussion

Each time I cannot remember what [OP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253162/what-is-an-op-when-referring-to-stack-exchange) stands for, I think it would be more kind to use asker, poster, question author or anything that would be easier to understand without a trip to the [glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354) and/or without a search on the internet.

Should we use such acronyms, even if they may be widely used on the internet and/or only on Stack Exchange?

Comment: OP isn't a SE specific term. It's pretty widely used.

Comment: Maybe I should have asked that any *pretty widely used* term should not get used. It might be that someone who is not a native internet citizen or someone from another mother tongue visits any SE site (maybe one not related to computers at all) and gets discouraged to join the discussion.

Comment: When I don't know a term or abbreviation, I type it into google. I get pretty good [results](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OP)

Comment: I did that search too and found this: [OP acronym](http://www.acronymfinder.com/OP.html). Dozens of meanings like your linked article. It doesn't make it any clearer or easier to understand for anyone who doesn't know that upfront. I think such acronyms should be avoided not only in comments - but if you avoid them in questions and answers as @DavidZ suggests it is a good start.

Comment: Dozens of meanings, sure, but the relevant ones are [right on top](http://i.imgur.com/uIbPS5S.png) (the second one even has more info). It's also quite clear on the [wikipedia page](http://i.imgur.com/AhJeTdx.png). But, whatever.

Comment: @5pike please post it as an answer if you think we should use such acronyms and under which conditions. I think the question by itself is more than valid.

Comment: @downvoters - is the question itself so bad? Please suggest corrections or edit it. I think the topic is important.. if any of you has a good answer please provide it.

Comment: @flob, for what it's worth, I also dislike the use of "OP" on Stack Exchange (we're not Reddit and we're not 4chan) but I never felt the urge to bicker about it. I just do not use it myself, 's all.

Comment: @flob votes on meta sites often indicate agreement or disagreement with the post. People are probably downvoting because they don't agree that this policy should be implemented, not because they think your question is bad. (I've seen a lot of bad questions and this is not one.)

Comment: @DavidZ that's sad. Downvoting reduces visibility and it feels like those people don't want this question to be visible. Like they want to stay in their cosy community without any newcomers welcome. I would rather prefer a 'You are so dumb, just google it' as an answer - you could argue about it and vote upon it...

Comment: Ok, I rephrased the question to be more open and not so biased.. hope this helps for its topic.

Comment: @flob (2 comments up) I don't think so. If most people disagree with a feature request then it makes sense not to give it much visibility, in my opinion. I don't see at all how it's justified to conclude from this behavior that people want to stay in their cosy community and exclude newcomers (nor do I see the point of an answer that says "you're so dumb, just Google it" - note that such answers and comments _are_ actually [banned or highly discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links)).

Comment: @DavidZ My intend was to start a discussion, not a feature-request. If someone thinks we should not discuss this topic, you are right. But a comment with any kind of opinion would be more helpful. Seems like I got carried away with my suggested answer and the alleged motivation.

Comment: @flob sorry, I misspoke. What I said applies for suggestions of any sort, not just actual feature requests. In this case, you were originally suggesting that we discourage people from using these acronyms; people evidently disagreed, and they downvoted accordingly. In its current form, the question is a better prompt for discussion (although you've changed it so much that the existing answers don't _entirely_ make sense anymore, which is _somewhat_ frowned upon). I'm just saying, you can't conclude from the downvotes that people don't think this topic should be discussed.

Comment: I would add, though, that if avoiding downvotes is your goal, you're going to find participation in any meta site rather discouraging. It's the nature of meta sites that downvotes are used liberally.

Comment: @DavidZ (2 comments up) I tried to change the question to be more open and not so biased towards a direction without invalidating existing answers - Seems like I did not do the best job and I am sorry about that. But letting it go or submitting the question again with another point of view seemed worse... ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/800/discussion-between-flob-and-david-z).

Comment: You're right.  From now on, I'm using POS or SOB to refer to the asker.

Answer (score 12):

OP = "original poster" or "original post" so you're saving 11 or 13 bytes, not 4, and that could be important in a comment. Besides, OP is a well-known internet shorthand. [Not well-known to everyone](http://xkcd.com/1053/), of course, but it's common enough among people who participate in these interactions that it not only saves bytes, it saves brainpower on the part of the reader and writer. So I don't think it's such a big deal in comments or chat. If someone isn't familiar with the term, they can ask, and someone will explain it to them.

In questions and answers, sure, I agree that use of OP should be discouraged. It's likely to be ambiguous anyway, so instead of saying "OP" or "original post(er)" it's better to actually link to the page or post in question and say "[flob's question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243941/56541)" for example.

More generally, for other acronyms, especially those which seem to be SE-specific... it probably varies from case to case, but I think the same general rule applies, that most of these things are not really doing much harm in comments or chat, but in questions and answers they should be avoided.

Comment: Use them in comments, avoid them in questions and answers sounds reasonable :-) But if you need those 13 bytes and can't fit your comment in 600 characters there might be something else to improve?

Comment: I love your linked xkcd :-) So maybe I am one of the lucky 10k today? :-)

Comment: @flob (2 comments up) yeah, it's rare that that becomes an issue. My bigger point was that comments are ephemeral and chat is informal, so I don't think it's worth the effort to enforce this in those contexts. We can let things go in comments and chat even though they wouldn't be okay in a question or answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have raised a valid point.

English is my first and virtually only language.  I've earned my living from information systems for over 25 years. I'm very comfortable with many abbreviations from many industries, including Defence that makes an art of them, and yet I find **OP** is one of the hardest and least intuitive abbreviations that I have ever committed to memory.

Personally, I never use it because I think asker gets my message across far more clearly.

Another abbreviation of which I am not a fan is **tl;dr** for the same reasons as above.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should discourage use of such acronyms

- It would lower the barrier for new users.
- It would be more kind to non-internet citizens.
- It would be easier to understand for those who do not have English as their first language.

I once read somewhere on Stack Exchange that you should read your answer as if your mother would be standing behind you. It was more about kindness than comprehensibility but I think it is rude to new members of the community to put these kind of unneeded barriers in front of them.

Comment: As a suggestion, and remember that I agree with the point you have raised, the word rude is one that can be inflammatory so perhaps reword to simply "it is an unnecessary barrier to new members of the community".

Comment: Sorry, I think it is more than a barrier, it is plain rude.