# Can we add whatexactlyisyourquestion.com to the blocklist?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, blocklist

I just stumbled on this and I think we might do well to squash it before it becomes a wide spread problem.

http://whatexactlyisyourquestion.com/

I found a particular user, who shall remain nameless, who has already posted 32 comments containing little more than this link.

Comment: This is at least as snarky and unhelpful as lmgtfy.com. Possibly more, since the latter, at least, you end up with a possibly useful Google search.

Comment: Agree. It's a bad joke in the best case, direct offence at worst.

Comment: Ah, yes, the old "a post can't possibly be valid without a question mark" canard. Apply dragonfire.

Comment: Please flag those comments so mods can rain fire upon them.

Comment: If it's only one person who is doing this, wouldn't it make more sense to just flag those comments, rather than modifying the blacklist?  (Modifying the blacklist presumably requires developer time, which is precious -- if it can be addressed reasonably through existing mechanisms, that seems sufficient.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Posts are _questions_. This is a _question and answer repository_. There are rare exceptions but in general a decent question actually contains a, y'know, question. Not that I'm using that to condone this particular site or those particular comments.

Comment: Agreed, @Lightness, the _vast_ majority of Q posts here should include a grammatical question. But "Does your question contain a sentence
which ends in a question mark?" (quoting from the linked site) is not the bright-line test for "it's understandable what you need" that the link and its users would make it out to be.

Comment: @Josh: I generally agree. Although a tangential note of caution here that "we can understand what this OP needs if we concentrate hard enough" is not sufficient to meet SO's quality standards. This is a Q&A repository rather than a personal helpdesk so it's desirable for a question to be _clearly_ stated, as a question, for the benefit of all humanity for the rest of our days!

Comment: The website is dead, so the question is moot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ban LMGTFY (let me google that for you) links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links)