# Let-me-google-this-for-you link went through

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, lmgtfy

I happened to post a comment which contained a lmgtfy link.  Then I realized it was not nice, so I reposted it with a plain Google link.  After having been informed it was actually banned and [there was a mechanism to prevent it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links), I started wondering if it was a bug.

The post where this happened is here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/104886/6219

Comment: The blacklist entry for LMGTFY is not active on all sites, DBA might not be one of them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That blacklist is currently only active on a few sites, like Stack Overflow and Server Fault, because those are the sites that were having problems with it most. If another site starts having problems with its use in the future, they can request it be added for their site.

---

Shog was <s>irritated</s> nice enough to go ahead and apply that blacklist rule network-wide, so you shouldn't be able to use it anywhere now.

Comment: Tired of these questions and have the tools to just copy blacklists everywhere now, so... It's network-wide with the exception of MSE.

Comment: @Shog9 tired of which questions? :)  Anyway, thanks for doing it, as some sites attract more and more traffic and people, this gets a problem sooner or later.

Comment: @Shog9 Can we finally ban tvtropes links too? ;)

Comment: @Shog9 [LMDDGTFY](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=Shog9%20*is*%20a%20floating%20head!)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/G8ZTW.jpg