# Blacklist hxxp://bfy.tw/* as LMGTFY shortener

Tags: feature-request, blocklist, short-links

Can we get a global automatic blacklist on the link shortener at `bfy.tw`?  It's recently been used as an alternative to other shorteners, and I've seen at least two "Let me google that for you" links shortened with this shortener on multiple sites (or at the very least, Ask Ubuntu, today)

---

**Edit** It's been noted this is owned by LMGTFY, so I've revised the title.

Comment: bfy.tw appears to [be registered to LMGTFY, LLC](http://whois.domaintools.com/bfy.tw). "Shortening" lmgtfy links produces bfy.tw URLs, and I have not discovered another method to create them. I'm under the impression that bfy.tw is an URL-shortening (or obfuscating) service solely for lmgtfy. Since [lmgtfy links are blacklisted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15650), this should be a no-brainer.