# Yellow sections on posts

Tags: support, markdown, editor

This is probably a very stupid question, but I'm not too technologically inclined. I see often when someone 's post is containing an excerpt from a book or an article, recommended changes, etc. it's often on a yellow surface. Someone has even edited my post containing an excerpt from my own book to have a yellow background. I didn't mind it, but it furthered my curiosity as to how one does this.

Comment: Are you asking about cite blocks (quoted text)?

Comment: BTW a great way to find out how certain things were formatted in a post, you can press on the *edit* button under a post, and it will show you all the tricks used.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this comment is totally not needed. (Same low level as [LMGTFY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply prepend your text with a greater-than sign.

`> This is quoted text`

results in

> This is quoted text

Many more details available when clicking the question mark in the upper right of the post editor, including a link to the full [Markdown Editing Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page.

Comment: Yes, thank you! But does that mean I have to have greater-than sign for every line in my quoted text? @ale

Comment: Just highlight your text and click the double-quote button to see the greater than signs placed appropriately.

Comment: @PolyGeo Except "appropriately" is not the same as "as necessary"... you only need one greater than sign per paragraph.