# I googled that for you

Tags: discussion, ethics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers)
>   [How should we deal with Google questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions)

I have been going through a lot of questions that I have skipped, because when I read them, I think: "That can easily be googled". And sometimes I google those questions, come up with answers but just doesn't seem worth to post. This is more of like a moral dilemma and if those questions should be flagged as Other:"*you can google that*". Or is that too harsh of me. Should those questions be down-voted?

Edit:

From a [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links) in the comments:

> Questions with an answer that is trivial to find on Google are not
>   helping the SO community. They are generating superfluous reputation,
>   lowering the bar for asking genuine questions, and generally wasting
>   people's time.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links As for cases like you describe, I'd post the answer-links you discover into question comments.

Comment: Great question, totally related!

Comment: Related: [How should we deal with Google questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions)

Comment: Hmm .. should I close this question being that there are already a few discussions?

Comment: Related: [Introduce a “general reference” close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason).... [tag:status-declined], alas.

Comment: Oh, don't worry, we've become quite efficient at closing questions. \*eg\*

Comment: Or...[well, just google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=just+google+it+site%3Ameta.stackoverflow.com). ;) But to add something constructive, with enough time and knowledge nearly every question can be answered with a Google-Link. Though, some easier then others. The question is: Do you know it from the top of your head, or do you know how to find the answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Should those questions be down-voted?

Yes, yes, **yes!**

If something is **completely** and **trivially** answerable through Googling (like, you enter the question title and arrive at a full, satisfactory answer immediately, not after reading some huge document, but *immediately*), please

- Downvote
- Leave a polite comment that this is trivial to Google; if appropriate, point out which search keywords can be used
- Closevote. A ["general reference" close reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason) was declined for fear of misuse, so there isn't a really good close reason for this case; I, personally, tend to vote to close as Not a Real Question instead.

**Don't**

- post an answer with a Google link
- post a "Let me Google that for you" link
- be rude

Comment: +1 for "Leave a polite comment".

Comment: Makes sense and reading about the superfluous reputation it generates, probably also down-vote those answers?

Comment: If it's a first-time user, I'd leave the polite answer, suggest removing the question, and wait a while before downvoting.