# Is SO supposed to be a knowledge database?

Tags: discussion

I think it should be. Reading [Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers) gives me confidence I'm not the only one. But I got burned today. I asked a question ([Setting up Python for web development on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009388/setting-up-python-for-web-development-on-windows)) with a sort of long introduction, hoping it will help generate detailed answers in a true knowledge-database style.

Unfortunately, an experienced user saw my introduction as off-topic, deleted it, and I got a few answers that have little to do with my question, before others closed it, because it "will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion".

OK, humor may be perceived as off-topic, but my introduction was a part of the question, and without it, the question has a totally different meaning. Now it's useless to me and everyone else.

When you see a trivial question, or the one that you find stupid, to long, unclear, whatever... Should you edit it to your likeness, close it, downvote it without explanation, or call it stupid in a comment or an answer? Would that be constructive? **Or should you try and explain why it's not good, why it probably won't get any good answers, educate the asker, or just ignore it if you don't care wasting time?**

I don't mind being downvoted, that's what the voting system is for, but please don't change my words. They won't pollute the Internet. And if someone would spare this hour of her/his time to post the answer to my question as asked originally, I think that could be of big help to many. So, why preventing them, it's not your time they're going to be wasting.

**EDIT:** I got it all wrong. If majority of people see my intro as noise - it's noise. Knowledge database should not hold any noise, and in order to avoid it, questions should be asked in purely technical manner.

Comment: How is wrapping your intro in `<rant></rant>` tags supposed to make people think this is supposed to be taken as a joke and not a rant?

Comment: Even after reading it, I completely fail to see how that chunk of text added anything of value to the question.

Comment: People are *encouraged* to vote on content that they don't deem a good fit for the site. That's how the quality is maintained. The "if you don't like it why don't you leave it alone" principle is essential for, say, a real-world pluralist society, but it's terrible for a Q&A site. Places like Yahoo Answers or [Askville](http://askville.amazon.com/Index.do) are the result

Comment: I'm aware of the fact that we perceive things differently, and that my intro maybe isn't seen by others as intended, by what good deleting it adds to the value of the question?

Comment: @Pekka As I sad, please downvote my question, don't change it. Or delete it if it's not for this site, but don't change it.

Comment: @Zemljoradnik: Stack Overflow is for questions and answers. Not meta-talk about your feelings/attitude/state-of-mind regarding the state of tutorials about X followed by a question. Anything that's not directly related to your actual question is superfluous. If you feel that your question now is lacking things you want it to contain, edit it - but make it a question. Don't add pages of unrelated stuff. Stick to the point.

Comment: @Zemljoradnik that's not how the place works. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing If that's not to your liking, you probably need to go elsewhere (and I mean this completely without hostility or snark)

Comment: @Pekka I know that's not the way how the place works, that's why I started this discussion, to see if someone agrees with me that this should maybe be changed. It looks like no one does. :)

Comment: @Mat Thanks (can't upvote yet), your last comment is helpful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, Stack Overflow is aiming to be an easily searchable repository of commonly asked technical questions with focused answers. To that goal, we want focused questions where people don't have to read a multi-paragraph setup in order to get to the meat of the question. Everyone over a certain reputation level has the ability to edit questions and answers to refine them towards this goal.

Your intro:

> **`<rant>`** I don't understand why is it so hard to write a good explanation/guide/tutorial, to include some kind of graphical
>   representation of what is going on, to explain each step so one can
>   understand what she/he is doing and not just carbon copy (so she/he
>   could know what to google when the problem arises in the course of
>   installation/setup).
>
> Yes, I know most/all of these tools are for free, and people make them
>   and write guidelines in there spare time so newbies can use them
>   without having to read tons of books, and get to know all the
>   technologies involved, but... I do staff for free too, and help
>   people, but if I give a hungry man a can of food, I won't tell him "go
>   find a can opener for yourself" if I have one in my back pocket.
>
> If I understand the purpose of Stack Overflow, this should be the
>   place where you can find the answers you need in a familiar format,
>   not the links to possible answers in an unfamiliar format. Of course I
>   can google (I did google before I posted the question, and was
>   overwhelmed by vast variety of tutorials and answers to questions
>   similar to mine, that were not really helpful in my specific case),
>   but I think this post nailed it: [Embrace the non-Googlers][1]. If no
>   one would have an answer to this question, hopefully I will find it
>   myself and give the can opener to other hungry people out
>   there.**`</rant>`**

has nothing to do with the core technical issue you're asking about, and is unnecessary here. Therefore, the edit to remove it was justified. Why should someone visiting the site in the future care about your feelings towards other tutorials? They're going to hit your question to find out an answer to what you're asking, and they want to read only items relevant to that.

Comment: OK, I see I missed the point with that intro if no one understood it. The point was "can anyone give me the answer without just linking to the stuff I already read, and saying you don't need that". Which is what I got in the end. And what am I trying to say now is "has editing my question helped someone?", and "would it heart someone if it was intact?"

Comment: @Zemljoradnik, it is noise that detracts from the substance of your question. It's annoying to read though three paragraphs of something that turns out to be irrelevant. It runs counter to the "just the Qs and the As, please" mentality of SO that we love, and has helped SO succeed, by attracting and keeping those of us put off by the endless discussion in phpBB-style web forums.